# C++ Error: macro "[ClassName]" requires X arguments, but only 1 given

Tags: c++, class, macros, constructor

I have simple RGB color class but I keep getting this error and a bunch of others. I've searched for anything related to this but I cannot find anything that could help me.

When I include the class it self and try to make an instance it works. But when I include the Core class I keep getting these errors:

```
||=== Build: Win32 Release in Sandbox (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
[ProjectDir]\source\Base\RGB.hpp|11|error: macro "RGB" requires 3 arguments, but only 1 given|
[ProjectDir]\source\Base\RGB.hpp|12|error: macro "RGB" requires 3 arguments, but only 1 given|
[ProjectDir]\source\Base\RGB.hpp|15|error: macro "RGB" requires 3 arguments, but only 1 given|
[ProjectDir]\source\Base\RGB.hpp|16|error: macro "RGB" requires 3 arguments, but only 1 given|
[ProjectDir]\source\Base\RGB.hpp|18|error: macro "RGB" requires 3 arguments, but only 1 given|
[ProjectDir]\source\Base\RGB.hpp|11|error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]|
[ProjectDir]\source\Base\RGB.hpp|12|error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]|
[ProjectDir]\source\Base\RGB.hpp|13|error: expected identifier before '(' token|
[ProjectDir]\source\Base\RGB.hpp|13|error: expected ')' before '|' token|
[ProjectDir]\source\Base\RGB.hpp|13|error: expected ')' before '|' token|
[ProjectDir]\source\Base\RGB.hpp|13|error: expected ')' before '|' token|
[ProjectDir]\source\Base\RGB.hpp|15|error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]|
[ProjectDir]\source\Base\RGB.hpp|16|error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]|
[ProjectDir]\source\Base\RGB.hpp|18|error: invalid use of destructor '~RGB' as a type|
||=== Build failed: 14 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s)) ===|
```

Upfront: There's no macro named RGB so I don't know what's messing up the constructor.

I'm sorry for the lack of a specific question but I'm simply stuck and I have no idea what's causing this.

I would have posted the code for both the RGB and Core class but they have other dependencies and would be too much code to post. That's why I'll have a link to my [Github repository](https://github.com/iSLC/VC-MP-AngelScript-Module) where I have the code.

I'm not asking for someone to go through my code and fix it but whether if anyone encountered another problem like this and what could cause it. Thank you for your time and sorry for ambiguous question.

IDE: Code::Blocks [DevBuilds]

Compiler: MinGW-w64 4.9.1 x32 [rev3]

Comment: Well, there clearly is a macro named `RGB` somewhere (or perhaps a command line definition or some such).

Comment: Look into the preprocessed form of your code. I guess that something has a `#define RGB(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro for RGB comes up whenever you include the file Windows.h, it would be best to just rename your function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162937(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you. That was included by one of the libraries that I was using ( https://github.com/brofield/simpleini ). I haven't noticed that until I started to eliminate each included file individually.